# ¿Cómo cambiar de nombres a las columnas de varios dataframes en R?

Tags: r, rstudio, dataframe, names

Tengo los siguientes dataframes:

```
df1, df2, df3, df4, ..., df300   # Tengo 300 data frame.
```

Cada uno con 4 columas con distintos nombres. Es decir, los 300 dataframes tienen cuatro columnas pero todas con distitntos nombres.  A esos 300 dataframe les tengo que aplicar un `rbind`. Pero para la aplicación de esta función es necesario que los nombres de las columnas sean iguales.

No sé como especificar una función que me soluciones este problema. Es decir, como hago para colocar a los 300 dataframe un mismo nombre por columna.

**Muchas gracias de antemano.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basándome en lo que has comentado, tienes algo así:

```
df1 <- data.frame(A=runif(5), B=runif(5))
df2 <- data.frame(X=runif(5), Y=runif(5))
df3 <- data.frame(R=runif(5), T=runif(5))
```

En este ejemplo, 3 `data.frame` con la misma estructura pero distintos nombres de columna, lo cual ciertamente te impide unirlos mediante `rbind()`. Para unificar esto, te sugiero en primer lugar construir una lista con cada `df` y luego "aplicar" la función `setNames` sobre cada uno.

```
listadf <- list(df1, df2, df3)
listadf <- lapply(listadf, setNames, c("Col_1", "Col_2"))
```

con esto hemos modificado los nombres de columna de cada `df` dentro de la lista (los originales siguen igual). Finalmente, teniendo una lista podemos "aplicar" `rbind()` a cada elemento de la misma para generar un único `df`:

```
do.call(rbind, listadf)
```

**Truco**: Para generar la lista, no necesariamente debes escribir los 300 nombres, puedes usar `ls()` para generarla: `listadf <- lapply(ls(pattern ="^df\\d+$"), get)`

Comment: Muchísimas gracias estimado Patricio. Que gran aporte.